# How can I search `subsegment` by name in AWS xray console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-xray

I am running lambda in AWS and enabled xray. Below is a code I use to create a subsegment inside lambda. I can see this subsegment when I click a trace. How can I search all traces with this subsegment by name in xray console?

```
await AWSXRay.captureAsyncFunc('create-connection', async () => {
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the X-Ray console, you can only search for traces with segment names as each segment typically represents a service. Subsegment names searches are not supported.

What you can do instead is [add an annotation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs-segment.html#xray-sdk-nodejs-segment-annotations) to the [created subsegment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs-subsegments.html#xray-sdk-nodejs-subsegments-lambda). Something like this should work:

```js
await AWSXRay.captureAsyncFunc('create-connection', function(subsegment) => {
  subsegment.addAnnotation("mykey", "my value");
  ...
```

Since annotations are indexed, in the X-Ray console you can search traces with annotation like `annotation.mykey = "my value"`